# Play a Sound when a cell is tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview, avaudioplayer

I'm working on a project where when a cell in a tableview is pressed, a sound will play. I have put my sounds into an array, like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
//Data
soundArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [Sounds soundOfCategory:@"Sound" name:@"clipOne"],
              [Sounds soundOfCategory:@"Sound" name:@"clipTwo"],
              [Sounds soundOfCategory:@"Sound" name:@"clipThree"],
              nil];
//Reload the table
[[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

I'm using the following to play the sound:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

//Create new Sound Object
Sounds *sound = nil;
sound = [soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Configure the cell
[[cell textLabel]setText:[sound name]];
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

return cell;
}

-(void)PlayClip:(NSString *)soundName
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL     fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

[theAudio play];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
[self PlayClip:[soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

But with no luck. I receive the error :  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Sounds length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa35d720'

What is the issue? Is there a better way to play the sound? I'm new to working with tableviews, so please forgive my ignorance.

Thanks!

Comment: Unrecognized selector sent to instance usually involves a type mismatch. Typically its because you are setting a value of one data type to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in the last line of your code:

```
[self PlayClip:[soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; // PlayClip:(NSString *)
```

[soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] returns `Sounds` not `NSStrintg`.

I think it should be:

```
[self PlayClip:[[soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]];
```

Comment: This fixed the issue! Thanks!  However, now the sound isn't playing at all... The app doesn't crash when the cell is tapped (like it was doing before), but no audio is coming through.